# What is the virbr0 interface used for?

Tags: configuration, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

```
      virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a2:17:ea:e3:47:7e  
      inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

can anyone tell me what this interface does and how I can change the IP address? I want to see if it is the reason my guests cannot connect.

Answer (score 81):

The `virbr0`, or "Virtual Bridge 0" interface is used for NAT (Network Address Translation). It is provided by the `libvirt` library, and virtual environments sometimes use it to connect to the outside network.

It was likely bundles with a VM software you installed at some point. If you'd like to remove it, and you're sure nothing else depends on it, you can use the following command:

```
sudo brctl delbr virbr0
```

(from [UbuntuForums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1815973))

It is unlikely that the virtual bridge is affecting your guests' ability to connect to the Internet, though.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. Do you know how i can change the address that was assigned by default?

Comment: it looks like my guests are being assigned to the virbr0 bridge even though the ip is in a different range and I can not assign the interface to br0.

Comment: You may need to run `sudo ip link set dev virbr0 down` first to disable the interface. Thanks +1

Comment: What if it just started showing up out of the blue?

Comment: How to make sure that nothing depends in it?

Answer (score 13):

If you are unable to connect to the internet due to "vibr0" interface then follow the commands below

```
virsh net-destroy default
virsh net-undefine default
service libvirtd restart
ifconfig
```

Answer (score 11):

For changing the ip address of virbr0 under ubuntu 12.04

```
sudo cp /var/lib/libvirt/network/default.xml /tmp/default.xml
sudo vi /tmp/default.xml # edit the ip address
sudo virsh net-destroy default
sudo virsh net-undefine default
sudo virsh net-define /tmp/default.xml
sudo virsh net-start default
```

You could refer to: http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Networking

Answer (score 1):

My answer is a mix of previous answers, but that's how I could make it to work for me:

```
cp /var/lib/libvirt/network/default.xml /tmp/default.xml
vi /tmp/default.xml # edit the ip address
sudo virsh net-destroy default
sudo virsh net-undefine default   # needed to avoid errors below
sudo virsh net-define /tmp/default.xml
sudo virsh net-start default
rm /tmp/default.xml
```

Comment: How is this different from [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/342364/214264) answer?

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha Without the undefine, the define command says it cannot create a new "default".  It simply did not work for me.

Comment: Then, please include this little but perhaps important piece of information. So, if in future anybody face with the same issue, knows how to solve it

Answer (score 1):

I am using `virtualbox 5.2.28` on `ubuntu-16.04` and the config file is in `/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf`

maybe you can always check the conf file location by checking the cmdline of the `dnsmasq` process.

To check the process number, port, and name.

```
sudo netstat -plant
```

To check the cmdline and find from where it loads the configuration file use

```
cat /proc/<PID>/cmdline
```