# Ubuntu server 12.04 on VirtualBox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, network-bridge

I can't connect to internet. I lost eth0.

My VirtualBox network is Attached to : Bridged Adapter, 
                         Name        : wlan0

[image: VM Network Settings]

Network configuration fails at VM boot

[image: failures on boot]

[image: ifconfig of VM]

`apt-get update` is failing due to DNS resolution failure.

[image: apt errors]

Comment: Do you have wlan0?

Comment: i have wlan0 on my computer,but on virtualbox under the command ifconfig  appear "lo"connection  and "virbr0" connection

Comment: Please upload a screen shot of the network settings for the VM in question to imgur.com or similar image host and [edit] your question to provide a link so we can see what your settings are. This will help us help you! Thank you!

Comment: http://imgur.com/oCCc6ZO,Gbi8rmK,FdijZNZ,aEXjpA9#0

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/246343/what-is-the-virbr0-interface-used-for

Comment: You may also find this useful: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-kvm-disable-virbr0-nat-interface/

Comment: I'm glad your problem is resolved. Please consider adding your own answer to this question so that others with the same problem can benefit.

Answer (score 1):

First I set the machine **attached: NAT** and started up the server the reload the network

```
sudo /etc/init.d/network reload
```

then I shut down the server and set the attached to **bridge Adapter** and started up the machine, and typed these commands:

```
sudo virsh net-destroy default
sudo virsh net-undefine default
sudo service libvirtd restart
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing your settings to match the below will return your eth0 connection to your VM.

[image: VMnic]

Then Reboot the VM

If this doesn't work for you, drop me a comment.

Comment: :(   it did not work  http://imgur.com/UZugAl6,tYyOXY0#0

Comment: Did you reboot the VM?