# I'm running 18.04 LTS server with KVM and cannot connect to the VMs from my local network

Tags: networking, server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

Hi I've successfully installed KVM and built several different machines both Windows and Linux, and they can all see the internet and run, but from my local 192.168.1.0 network, I cannot connect to them with tools like SSH. The servers IP address is assigned to br0, and all of the VMs are running on

```
virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:7b:16:92  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Here is my netplan:

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
      enp8s0f0:
         dhcp4: no
         dhcp6: no
    bridges:
      br0:
        interfaces: [enp8s0f0]
        dhcp4: yes*
```

Do I need to create static routes on my main router, or what am I missing?

Comment: What is the IP address of one of your VMs? Is SSH installed? Is the firewall configured to allow SSH connections? This will explain more about the virbr0 interface: https://askubuntu.com/questions/246343/what-is-the-virbr0-interface-used-for#246346

Comment: There is no firewall running, SSH is running, IP address is 192.168.122.117 If I try to  SSH from the host to the vm I get 'ssh: connect to host 192.168.122.117 port 22 no route to host. From the vm I can ssh back into itself or to another host on the 192.168.1.0 network.

Comment: From **virsh**, run `net-edit default` and post the results to your question.

Comment: <network>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>9309af71-4802-4681-8adb-b2a80befaee6</uuid>
  <forward mode='nat'/>
  <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:7b:16:92'/>
  <ip address='192.168.122.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.122.2' end='192.168.122.254'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>

Comment: Hmmm...this is pretty much exactly how mine is setup. I'm going to have to research this more.

Comment: I'm guessing that I'm just missing something simple, I know I could do it with static routes, but was hoping to make it automatic, and simple.

Comment: I think I found the missing link, I had to go to my default router and add a static route back to the guest network 192.168.122.0 pointed to the host server 192.168.1.128. Still checking that everything works, but looks better.